# chef-server-api : `CURL` post to Chef Server failed

Tags: bash, curl, post, chef-infra

I wrote a Bash script to implement Chef APIs like `GET` and `POST`.

Now `GET` works perfect, while `POST` fails.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Chef Server API by bash.

set -x
_chomp () {
  # helper function to remove newlines
  awk '{printf "%s", $0}'
}

chef_api_request() {
  # This is the meat-and-potatoes, or rice-and-vegetables, your preference really.

  local method path body timestamp chef_server_url client_name hashed_body hashed_path
  local canonical_request headers auth_headers

  chef_server_url="https://chef.xxx.com:9443"
  ca_cert="/root/.chef/trusted_certs/chef.xxx.com.crt"

  method=$1
  endpoint=${2%%\?*}
  body=$3

  path=${chef_server_url}$2
  client_name="opscode" # from `knife user list`, and the one who is associated with the org when created by `chef-server-ctl org-create`



  hashed_path=$(echo -n "$endpoint" | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl enc -base64)
  hashed_body=$(echo -n "$body" | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl enc -base64)
  timestamp=$(date -u "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

  canonical_request="Method:$method\nHashed Path:$hashed_path\nX-Ops-Content-Hash:$hashed_body\nX-Ops-Timestamp:$timestamp\nX-Ops-UserId:$client_name"
  headers="-H X-Ops-Timestamp:$timestamp \
    -H X-Ops-Userid:$client_name \
    -H X-Chef-Version:12.15.8 \
    -H Accept:application/json \
    -H X-Ops-Content-Hash:$hashed_body \
    -H X-Ops-Sign:version=1.0"

  auth_headers=$(printf "$canonical_request" | openssl rsautl -sign -inkey \
    "/etc/chef/${client_name}.pem" | openssl enc -base64 | _chomp |  awk '{ll=int(length/60);i=0; \
    while (i<=ll) {printf " -H X-Ops-Authorization-%s:%s", i+1, substr($0,i*60+1,60);i=i+1}}')

  case $method in
    GET)
      eval "curl --cacert $ca_cert $headers $auth_headers $path"
      ;;
    POST)
     # Content-Type is needed when doing 'POST' and 'PUT'.
      eval "curl --cacert $ca_cert -H Content-Type:application/json $headers $auth_headers $path"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Unknown Method. " >&2
     exit 1
      ;;
    esac
  }

 chef_api_request "$@"
```

Now I am running with

```
  bash server_api.sh POST "/organizations"'{"name":"secure","full_name":"secure test1"}'
```

the error is `{"error":["Invalid signature for user or client 'opscode'"]}`

And from `access_log`, it seems `POST` does not take effect, `GET` is still used.

```
172.16.232.201 - - [17/Jul/2017:11:42:04 +0800]  "GET /organizations HTTP/1.1" 401 "0.008" 60 "-" "curl/7.29.0" "127.0.0.1:8000" "401" "0.007" "12.15.8" "version=1.0" "opscode" "2017-07-17T03:42:04Z" "eWa1il2mhfy0QqcQDhcZx3Jda4w=" 785
```

I know `POST` by `curl` will use `-d`, but from [server api docs](https://docs.chef.io/api_chef_server.html)

I am quite confused with using `-d`.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: You already posted this to the mailing list, you don't need to post it again. That said, why in the name of all that is holy are you trying to do this? It's probably not impossible, but using a real client library like `chef-api` or `PyChef` will be easier and more robust.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things.

First, you'll find it a bunch easier to debug this if, before the `eval` line, you do the same but with `echo` instead.  That will print your entire command out to the console, you can see what it's doing (and make sure it is formatted as you expect).  You can then copy/paste into bash to see what curl makes of it.

Second, when I look at my example `curl` commands lying around, I've been putting `-H` before each individual header, not `-H` then all of the headers necessary.  Right now, I'm wondering whether this is something you'll need to do, or if it's something I DON'T need to do.

But to the main point, to POST with curl:

- You tell it to post with `-X POST`
- Then you provide the data with the -d option

Probably something like this:

```
curl --cacert $ca_cert -H Content-Type:application/json $headers $auth_headers -X POST -d '$body' $path
```

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me. It works.
The official docs is a little bit confused. your guess is correct. 
Thanks again.

Comment: I had thought the `body` is `base64(sha1(BODY))` and don't need to appear  again in the `POST` request,which is totally wrong.

Comment: Oh, 'GET` from access.log is because I don't use `-X', which causes the default method is `GET`, it explains a lot.

 -X, --request <command>
              (HTTP) Specifies a custom request method to use when communicating with the HTTP server.  The specified request will be  used
              instead  of  the method otherwise used (which defaults to GET). 
              more.